# Modify the value of a key in a list of dictionaries using Ansible

Tags: list, dictionary, ansible

I am trying to modify a list of dictionaries in an Ansible playbook.  My dictionary is:

```yaml
    alist:  
    - foo: |
        hello world
        another line
      bar: xyz 
    - foo: |
        biz baz
      bar: abc 
    - bar: "123"
```

I need the resulting list to be:

```yaml
    alist:  
    - foo: |
        hello world
        another line
        a new line
      bar: xyz 
    - foo: |
        biz baz
        a new line
      bar: abc 
    - bar: "123"
      foo: a new line
```

Using a loop and the `combine` filter, I've been able to get the individual components looking close to the desired result.  But this results in 3 items instead of a combined list.  It also adds an extra newline before the newly inserted value.

```yaml
  - debug:  
      msg: "{{ _item  }}"
    vars:   
      _foos: "{{ item.foo | default('') }}"
      _item: "{{ item | combine({'foo': _foos+'\na anew line'}) }}"
    loop: "{{ alist }}"
```

Comment: That looks quite complex. Why do you want to do this? Perhaps restructure/re-organize improve simplicity.

Comment: I'm looking to insert data into a list of Apache HTTP virtual hosts to enable Let's Encrypt .well-known path.  This code also has to serve multiple environments.  A test environment using Let's Encrypt and another environment using certificates generated by a different CA.  This list feeds into "legacy" ansible to build the conf file.  Which is out of my control at the moment.

Comment: Perhaps try using templates for virtual hosts for Apache. Besides this role, there are plenty of other roles. It might be time to let  go of the legacy, and build a new world..
https://github.com/csuka/ansible_role_apache/blob/main/templates/vhosts.conf.j2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For me, this gives the proper result:

```yaml
---
- hosts: local_test
  gather_facts: false
  vars:
    new_alist: []
    alist:
      - foo: |
          hello world
          another line
        bar: xyz
      - foo: |
          biz baz
        bar: abc
      - bar: "123"
  tasks:
    - name: update dict w required values
      set_fact:
        new_alist: "{{ new_alist + [item | combine({ 'foo': (item.foo | default('') + 'a new line') | trim })] }}"
      loop: "{{ alist }}"
      loop_control:
        loop_var: item

    - name: print to screen
      debug:
        var: new_alist
```

This gives me:

```yaml
  new_alist:
  - bar: xyz
    foo: |-
      hello world
      another line
      a new line
  - bar: abc
    foo: |-
      biz baz
      a new line
  - bar: '123'
    foo: a new line
```

I'm using latest Ansible.

Answer (score 0):

I've found shorter solution, but it can be dangerous due to usage of out-of-python variable content formatting (i.e. I'm using fact that ansible get's from jinja string that it later re-parses from python or json representation):

```yaml
---
- hosts: localhost
  connection: local
  gather_facts: false
  vars:
    new_alist: []
    alist:
      - foo: |
          hello world
          another line
        bar: xyz
      - foo: |
          biz baz
        bar: abc
      - bar: "123"
  tasks:
    - name: show changed
      debug:
        var: new_alist
      vars:
        new_alist: "[{%for item in alist%}{{item | combine({ 'foo': (item.foo | default('') + 'a new line') | trim })|to_json}},{%endfor%}]"
```

Here are result (which is same as in answer before):

```
ANSIBLE_STDOUT_CALLBACK=yaml ansible-playbook -i localhost, qq1.yml
PLAY [localhost] ***************************************************************

TASK [show changed] ************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => 
  new_alist:
  - bar: xyz
    foo: |-
      hello world
      another line
      a new line
  - bar: abc
    foo: |-
      biz baz
      a new line
  - bar: '123'
    foo: a new line

PLAY RECAP *********************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0   

Playbook run took 0 days, 0 hours, 0 minutes, 0 seconds
```

Update: I've found less ugly solution that doesn't uses loop:

```yaml
---
- hosts: localhost
  connection: local
  gather_facts: false
  vars:
    new_alist: []
    alist:
      - foo: |
          hello world
          another line
        bar: xyz
      - foo: |
          biz baz
        bar: abc
      - bar: "123"
  tasks:
    - name: show changed
      debug:
        var: new_alist
      vars:
        new_alist: |
          {{ alist
           | zip( alist
                | map(attribute="foo",default="")
                | zip( alist
                     | map(attribute=omit,default="a new line"))
                | map("join")
                | map("community.general.dict_kv","foo"))
           | map("combine")}}
```

PS: I'm using Ansible 2.14.2.