# Why cannot I get a loop to work with a dictionary replacement in Ansible?

Tags: ansible

I have an Ansible playbook that will be pulling a list of VMs from a Nutanix Prism Central, capture the `vm_name` and the UUID, parse the short name of the VM, come up with the FQDN and then replace the `vm_name` with the FQDN.

I have issues replacing the `vm_name` in the dictionary variable using a loop.

I get:

> "The task includes an option with an undefined variable. The error was: str object has no element AnsibleUndefined(hint=None, obj=missing, name='loop')

I have created a minimal reproducible code:

```yaml
---
- name: Test of value replacement
  hosts: all
  gather_facts: False
  vars:
    clone_vm:
      - {  uuid: "ac1fd960-e19a-48f3-935b-442901ef5fee", vm_name: "vrtstart001.hs.local_clone1" }
      - {  uuid: "f44880f6-49aa-4ba3-8cba-403ff06f1c5e", vm_name: "vrtstsrs001.hs.local_clone1" }
    fqdns:
         - "vrtstart001.nadex.co"
         - "vrtstsrs001.nadex.co"


  tasks:
    - name: Show variable
      debug:
        msg:
        - "{{ clone_vm }}"
        - "{{ fqdns }}"

    - name: Replace vm_name with FQDN
      set_fact:
        clone_vm: "{{ clone_vm | map('combine', [{'vm_name': item[loop.index0]}]) }}"
      loop: "{{ fqdns }}"
      loop_control:
        loop_var: item

    - debug:
        msg: "{{ clone_vm }}"
```

If I replace `[{'vm_name': item[loop.index0]}]` with `[{'vm_name': item.[loop.index0]}]` I get a different error:

> template error while templating string: expected name or number. String: {{ clone_vm | map('combine', [{'vm_name': item.[loop.index0]}]) }}. expected name or number

Is there another way to refer to the current value in `fqdns` to replace the current value in `clone_vm`?

From

```yaml
- uuid: ac1fd960-e19a-48f3-935b-442901ef5fee
  vm_name: vrtstart001.hs.local_clone1
- uuid: f44880f6-49aa-4ba3-8cba-403ff06f1c5e
  vm_name: vrtstsrs001.hs.local_clone1
```

My desired output would be:

```yaml
- uuid: ac1fd960-e19a-48f3-935b-442901ef5fee
  vm_name: vrtstart001.nadex.co
- uuid: f44880f6-49aa-4ba3-8cba-403ff06f1c5e
  vm_name: vrtstsrs001.nadex.co
```

Comment: As @Zeitounator already pointed out in your, now deleted, other question, you cannot use the `loop.x` syntax without a proper use of the [extended loop syntax](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_loops.html#extended-loop-variables).

Comment: This said combining a list of dictionary into a list makes no sense whatsoever. Having your trial is a good starting point but the more important is having your input and desired output. Your question is still missing a desired output.

Comment: Even after adding "extended: true"  I get the same errors.

Comment: _I get the same errors_ > which? You have two different error message already in your question. Also everything you are trying should be [edit]ed in your question, not added as a comment, as it will help answer the actual question.

Comment: `Even after adding "extended: true" I get the same errors` <= because you did not fully read the [link](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_loops.html#extended-loop-variables) which was given to you several times already where you will learn that, after extending the loop as you already found out, you also need to use the correct names for the variables (e.g. `ansible_loop.index0`). Meanwhile, I have a hard time figuring out why you would actually need this at all in the above example.

Comment: @Zeitounator I read the link in it's entirety where it applied to extended loop syntax. I did use ansible_loop.index and got the same error.  Let me explain why I need it again. I am trying to replace the value of a dictionary item so that it reads as such in my desired output example. I will then include the logic in a much broader Ansible playbook that will change a name value in a database to the new name in the dictionary based on the UUID matching that new name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to @U880C's answer, I finally got what you are actually trying to do.

You do not need `set_fact` nor extended loop vars to achieve your goal (although you can use them, see example at bottom). The following self-explanatory playbook is an example that meets your requirement. You can run it with `-v` to get intermediate debugging to study the solution. Feel free to drop the intermediate vars to bring it down to a single jinja2 expression if you need.

```yaml
---
- name: Test of value replacement
  hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: False
  vars:
    clone_vm:
      - {  uuid: "ac1fd960-e19a-48f3-935b-442901ef5fee", vm_name: "vrtstart001.hs.local_clone1" }
      - {  uuid: "f44880f6-49aa-4ba3-8cba-403ff06f1c5e", vm_name: "vrtstsrs001.hs.local_clone1" }
    fqdns:
         - "vrtstart001.nadex.co"
         - "vrtstsrs001.nadex.co"

    _fqdns_dict_list: "{{ ['vm_name: '] | product(fqdns) | map('join') | map('from_yaml') }}"
    _synchronized_list: "{{ clone_vm | zip(_fqdns_dict_list) }}"
    clone_vm_transformed: "{{ _synchronized_list | map('combine') }}"


  tasks:
    - name: "Intermediate result: fqdns as a list of dicts"
      ansible.builtin.debug:
        var: _fqdns_dict_list
        verbosity: 1

    - name: "Intermediate result: synchronized list"
      ansible.builtin.debug:
        var: _synchronized_list
        verbosity: 1

    - name: "Final result: dict list with replaced vm_name"
      ansible.builtin.debug:
        var: clone_vm_transformed
```

Playbook demo run:

```
PLAY [Test of value replacement] ********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [Intermediate result: fqdns as a list of dicts] ************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
skipping: [localhost]

TASK [Intermediate result: synchonized list] ********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
skipping: [localhost]

TASK [Final result: dict list with replaced vm_name] ************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "clone_vm_transformed": [
        {
            "uuid": "ac1fd960-e19a-48f3-935b-442901ef5fee",
            "vm_name": "vrtstart001.nadex.co"
        },
        {
            "uuid": "f44880f6-49aa-4ba3-8cba-403ff06f1c5e",
            "vm_name": "vrtstsrs001.nadex.co"
        }
    ]
}

PLAY RECAP ******************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=2    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

---

For completeness and learning sake, here is an example using your original approach. This will create an unnecessary task running in a loop and possibly for every host in your play loop (although this last point can be optimized). So I consider this a bad practice in this situation and the goal below is just to show it is feasible.

The following playbook:

```yaml
---
- name: Test of value replacement
  hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: False
  vars:
    clone_vm:
      - {  uuid: "ac1fd960-e19a-48f3-935b-442901ef5fee", vm_name: "vrtstart001.hs.local_clone1" }
      - {  uuid: "f44880f6-49aa-4ba3-8cba-403ff06f1c5e", vm_name: "vrtstsrs001.hs.local_clone1" }
    fqdns:
         - "vrtstart001.nadex.co"
         - "vrtstsrs001.nadex.co"

  tasks:
    - name: Replace vm_name with FQDN
      vars:
        current_name:
          vm_name: "{{ item }}"
      ansible.builtin.set_fact:
        clone_vm_transformed: "{{ clone_vm_transformed | d([]) + [clone_vm[ansible_loop.index0] | combine(current_name)] }}"
      loop: "{{ fqdns }}"
      loop_control:
        extended: true

    - name: Show replacement result
      ansible.builtin.debug:
        var: clone_vm_transformed
```

gives:

```
PLAY [Test of value replacement] ********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [Replace vm_name with FQDN] ********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => (item=vrtstart001.nadex.co)
ok: [localhost] => (item=vrtstsrs001.nadex.co)

TASK [Show replacement result] **********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "clone_vm_transformed": [
        {
            "uuid": "ac1fd960-e19a-48f3-935b-442901ef5fee",
            "vm_name": "vrtstart001.nadex.co"
        },
        {
            "uuid": "f44880f6-49aa-4ba3-8cba-403ff06f1c5e",
            "vm_name": "vrtstsrs001.nadex.co"
        }
    ]
}

PLAY RECAP ******************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=2    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

Answer (score 1):

From your currently available description I understand that you like to achieve something like

```yaml
---
- name: Test of value replacement (domain part in vm_name)
  hosts: localhost
  become: false
  gather_facts: False

  vars:

    clone_vm:
      - uuid: "ac1fd960-e19a-48f3-935b-442901ef5fee"
        vm_name: "vrtstart001.hs.local_clone1"
      - uuid: "f44880f6-49aa-4ba3-8cba-403ff06f1c5e"
        vm_name: "vrtstsrs001.hs.local_clone1"

    domain: nadex.co

  tasks:

  - debug:
      msg:
       - "uuid: {{ item['uuid']}}"
       - "vm_name: {{ item['vm_name'] | regex_replace('hs.local_clone1', domain) }}"
    loop: "{{ clone_vm }}"
```

resulting into an output of

```yaml
TASK [debug] **************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => (item={u'vm_name': u'vrtstart001.hs.local_clone1', u'uuid': u'ac1fd960-e19a-48f3-935b-442901ef5fee'}) =>
  msg:
  - 'uuid: ac1fd960-e19a-48f3-935b-442901ef5fee'
  - 'vm_name: vrtstart001.nadex.co'
ok: [localhost] => (item={u'vm_name': u'vrtstsrs001.hs.local_clone1', u'uuid': u'f44880f6-49aa-4ba3-8cba-403ff06f1c5e'}) =>
  msg:
  - 'uuid: f44880f6-49aa-4ba3-8cba-403ff06f1c5e'
  - 'vm_name: vrtstsrs001.nadex.co'
```

This is neither a final nor the best approach and solution, but shows that it might be easier to loop over `clone_vm` instead and if that's really required.

Taking into account the example from [How to modify the value of a key in a list of dictionaries using Ansible?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76136254/6771046)

```yaml
  - name: update dict w required values
    debug:
      msg: "{{ item | combine({ 'vm_name': (item.vm_name | regex_replace('hs.local_clone1', domain) ) }) }}"
    loop: "{{ clone_vm }}"
    loop_control:
      loop_var: item
```

resulting into an output of

```yaml
TASK [update dict w required values] **************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => (item={u'vm_name': u'vrtstart001.hs.local_clone1', u'uuid': u'ac1fd960-e19a-48f3-935b-442901ef5fee'}) =>
  msg:
    uuid: ac1fd960-e19a-48f3-935b-442901ef5fee
    vm_name: vrtstart001.nadex.co
ok: [localhost] => (item={u'vm_name': u'vrtstsrs001.hs.local_clone1', u'uuid': u'f44880f6-49aa-4ba3-8cba-403ff06f1c5e'}) =>
  msg:
    uuid: f44880f6-49aa-4ba3-8cba-403ff06f1c5e
    vm_name: vrtstsrs001.nadex.co
```

Another example can be found under [Ansible: How to update list of dictionary based on certain condition?](https://serverfault.com/a/1067707/448950)

Comment: Thank you for the input. There will be an issue with just replacing the domain name as once this has been run against the whole 175 VMs you might have hs.localhs.local_clone1-1, hs.local_clone1-1, iggroup.local_clone1, as well as hs.local.clone1.  You could also end up with the correct domain name being nadex.co, internal.nadex.co, or hs.local. Which then basically calls for the FQDN obtained from the nslookup query which you don't see as I only put in enough of the code to replicate the issue.

Comment: The input was just intended as hint and to guide into a direction how it could probably become resolved. Therefore the link to [Ansible: How to update list of dictionary based on certain condition?](https://serverfault.com/q/1067692/448950) as that came very close to your Use Case. Your description could probably take advantage from an update with the information you've provided within your recent comments.